# Unable to Clone a record that has a Unique field

Tags: apex, clone

I have a scenario where I am trying to clone a custom object record which has a unique custom field. the unique field is : Tech_Unique__c. It is a Text field. When I am trying to clone I am getting this error : DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Tech_Unique__c duplicates value on record with id: a0B3Ld0000fsdf

```
for (Other__c record : [SELECT Id, Name, CurrencyIsoCode, RecordTypeId, 
Opportunity__c, Territory__c, Alliance__c, Client__c, Attribution__c, Source__c 
FROM Other_Parties__c WHERE Client__c =: originalRecord.Id]) 
{
    System.debug('record : ' + record );
    Other__c  OtherClone = record.clone(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
    OtherClone .Client__c = cloneRecord.Id;
    relatedToCloneList.add(OtherClone );
    System.debug('relatedToCloneList: ' + relatedToCloneList);
}
INSERT relatedToCloneList;
```

while inserting I am getting this error : DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: Tech_UniqueA__c duplicates value on record with id: a0B3Ld0000fsdf

Could you please help me to know where am I wrong?

Comment: Unique fields won't accept duplicate values, As you said Tech_Unique__c is a text field then it might be updated at back end via workflow/trigger/flow/process builder. You need to check and automate it such a way that it populates unique values to that field or you can check how is that field's value is formulated that you can change those relevant field values to get unique combination on cloning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Unique ID' field is a setting which prevents the same value from being used in multiple records for any specific field.

So try something like below

```
SObject clonedSObject = record.clone(false, false, false, false);

clonedSObject.put('Tech_Unique__c','Some random value that is unique');

INSERT clonedSObject;
```